# Android Listview: imageview in first element

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've a custom listview in my chat application. It shows some people I've already chatted with. I want the first element in the listview to be an imageview that, when clicked, gives the user the opportunity to type a new person he wants to chat with. I've already implemented that (I don't want to use ListView header), by adding one more element to the listview and then inflate the imageview or the textview according to the position...

```
View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        if (position == 0)
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_chat_list_header, parent, false);
        else
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_chat_list, parent, false);
    }

    TextView tvName = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id_chat_list_name));
    TextView tvPreview = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id_chat_list_preview));
    if ( tvName != null && tvPreview != null ) {
        ChatListElement p = getItem(position);
        tvName.setText(p.name);
        String preview = p.lastMessage;
        if (preview.length() > 30)
            preview = preview.substring(0, 30) + "...";
        tvPreview.setText(preview);
    }
    return v;
```

But, when I run it, I get some of the views in the middle were also turned into imageviews... I think it has something to do with recycled views in listview, but I don't understand how to make it work. 
Thank you very much

Comment: asked bazillion times ... [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) => adapter recycle the view

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Override `getViewTypeCount()` in your adapter to return `2`

Step #2: Override `getItemViewType()` in your adapter to return `0` for position `0` (your `ImageView`) and `1` for everything else (your normal rows)

Step #3: Use `getLayoutInflater()`, called on your `Activity`, not `LayoutInflater.from()` (not technically related to your problem, but you'll thank me later for helping ensure that your custom themes work as expected)

Steps #1 and #2 will teach the `ListView` to maintain two object pools, one for each type of row, and it ensures that the row you get back for recycling is of the right type for the requested position.